# Convert =C3=B6 to ö assuming UTF-8

Tags: c, utf-8

So I am trying to read an email, it is encoded in quoted printable and thus contains for example:

```
=C3=B6
```

That should be converted into

```
ö
```

So I get that c3b6 is the hex representation of the `utf-8` value `ö`, but I fail to actually understand how to convert a `char * str = '=C3=B6'` into `char * str 'ö'`.

I'm using linux but will port the code to windows so I want a multiplatform solution for this.

How can I do this?

Comment: iveqy, See [Unicode Character “ö”](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00F6) and look for _UTF-8 Encoding:_.  Is that enough?

Comment: @chux no, that just tells me that ö has the utf-8 hex representation of C3B6, but I already know this. My question is how I can convert the string =C3=B6 to binary (I believe).

So that the string str will print ö with printf('%s\n', str)

Comment: C does have this footnote about `fprintf()` and `s`:"No special provisions are made for multibyte characters." so a multiplatform solution will not necessarily work on all platforms.  What output do you get with `printf("%s\n", "\xC3\xB6")`? With  `printf("%s\n", "ö")`?

Comment: both prints ö, So then my only step (and the one I really struggle with) is how to go from const char * str = "=c3=b6"; to char * str = "\c3\b6"


  1 #include "stdio.h"
  2
  3 int main()
  4 {
  5         char * str = "=c3=b6";
  6         printf("%s\n", "ö");
  7         printf("%s\n", "\xC3\xB6");
  8         printf("%s\n", str);
  9         for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
 10                 if (str[i] == '=') {
 11                         str[i] = '\\';
 12                 }
 13         }
 14         printf("%s\n", str);
 15         return 0;
 16 }
 seg fault

Comment: It is UB to attempt to modify a string literal like `"\c3\b6"`.  That is the seg fault source.

Comment: Take a look at Chilkat MIME Library.  The form you are using is `quoted-printable` of a `UTF-8` entity. There should be no need to write custom code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to get OP started.

Parse the string `"=C3=B6"`, looking for 2 bytes as hexadecimal characters.  Then form a string to print (and hope `printf` will interpret as UTF-8) - Compliant compliers with `printf("%s", ...)` have "No special provisions are made for multibyte characters". [YMMV](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ymmv).

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main() {
  char * str = "=C3=B6";
  printf("%s\n", str);
  printf("1 %s\n", "ö");
  printf("2 %s\n", "\xC3\xB6");
  unsigned char a[3] = { 0 };
  if (sscanf("=c3=b6", "=%hhx=%hhx", &a[0], &a[1]) == 2) {
    printf("3 %s\n", a);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
=C3=B6
1 ö
2 ö
3 ö
```

Answer (score 1):

Decoding [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) strings involves three things:

- Ignore soft newlines. These are `=` followed by a newline.
- Convert `=` followed by two hexadecimal digits, to the character whose code matches that hexadecimal value

There are three main approaches to decoding data:

1. Input filter.  Instead of e.g. `fgetc()`, you use a function that reads and decodes the quoted-printable input.
2. Conversion to a new buffer.  See the `convert()` function in [Craig Esteys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54334309/1475978) to this same question.
3. Conversion in place.  This is possible, because every valid quoted-printable -encoded string is at least as long as the same decoded.

---

Input filter.  For simplicity, let's look at one char at a time. (Do note that many UTF-8 characters are longer than one char.)

First, we do need a helper function to convert hexadecimal digit characters to their respective arithmetic values:

```
static inline int hex_digit(const int c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case '0':           return  0;
    case '1':           return  1;
    case '2':           return  2;
    case '3':           return  3;
    case '4':           return  4;
    case '5':           return  5;
    case '6':           return  6;
    case '7':           return  7;
    case '8':           return  8;
    case '9':           return  9;
    case 'A': case 'a': return 10;
    case 'B': case 'b': return 11;
    case 'C': case 'c': return 12;
    case 'D': case 'd': return 13;
    case 'E': case 'e': return 14;
    case 'F': case 'f': return 15;
    default:            return -1;
    }
}
```

In most cases, you could also write that as

```
static inline int hex_digit(const int c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return c - '0';
    else
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
        return c - 'A' + 10;
    else
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'F')
        return c - 'a' + 10;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

or even as

```
static signed char  hex_digit_value[UCHAR_MAX + 1];

static inline int hex_digit(const int c)
{
    return hex_digit_value[(unsigned char)c];
}

static inline void init_hex_digit_values(void)
{
    int  i;
    for (i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++)
        hex_digit_value[i] = -1;

    hex_digit_value['0'] = 0;
    hex_digit_value['1'] = 1;
    hex_digit_value['2'] = 2;
    hex_digit_value['3'] = 3;
    hex_digit_value['4'] = 4;
    hex_digit_value['5'] = 5;
    hex_digit_value['6'] = 6;
    hex_digit_value['7'] = 7;
    hex_digit_value['8'] = 8;
    hex_digit_value['9'] = 9;
    hex_digit_value['A'] = hex_digit_value['a'] = 10;
    hex_digit_value['B'] = hex_digit_value['b'] = 11;
    hex_digit_value['C'] = hex_digit_value['c'] = 12;
    hex_digit_value['D'] = hex_digit_value['d'] = 13;
    hex_digit_value['E'] = hex_digit_value['e'] = 14;
    hex_digit_value['F'] = hex_digit_value['f'] = 15;
}
```

where `init_hex_digit_values()` is called once at the beginning of the program.  I prefer the first form as it is the most portable, but the second form is what you normally see.

The third form, using the `hex_digit_value[]` array, is an example of premature optimization.  It may be slightly faster than the others in some cases (but the differences are definitely too small to matter in practice), but it can be useful if one were to support widely different single-byte character sets (EBDIC and ASCII, for example) using the same code.

First, reading a decoded character from a stream (file or handle) that contains quoted-printable data:

```
int get_quoted_printable_char(FILE *from)
{
    int  c, c2, hi, lo;

    /* Paranoid check. */
    if (!from || ferror(from) || feof(from))
        return EOF;

    while (1) {

        c = fgetc(from);
        if (c != '=')
            return c;

        /* Soft newline? */
        c = fgetc(from);
        if (c == '\n')
            continue;

        /* '=' at the end of input? */
        if (c == EOF)
            return EOF;

        hi = hex_digit(c);
        if (hi < 0) {
            /* Invalid input; emit '=' instead. */
            ungetc(c, from);
            return '=';
        }

        c2 = fgetc(from);
        if (c2 == EOF) {
            /* Invalid input; emit '=' <c> instead. */
            ungetc(c, from);
            return '=';
        }

        low = hex_digit(c2);
        if (lo < 0) {
            /* Invalid input; try to emit '=' <c> <c2> instead. */
            ungetc(c2, from);
            ungetc(c, from);
            return '=';
        }

        return low + 16 * high;
    }
}
```

The loop is there in case the input has more than one consecutive soft-newline. It should not really happen, but if it did, we do want to ignore them all.

If you wanted to copy quoted-printable stream to a file, you'd only need the above and for example

```
int save(FILE *source, const char *filename)
{
    FILE  *target;
    int    c;

    if (!source || ferror(source))
        return -1;  /* Invalid source handle */

    if (!filename || !*filename)
        return -2;  /* Invalid filename */

    target = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (!target)
        return -3;  /* Cannot open filename for writing */

    while (1) {
        c = get_quoted_printable_char(source);
        if (c == EOF)
            break;

        if (fputc(c, target) == EOF)
            break;
    }

    if (!feof(source) || ferror(source)) {
        fclose(target);
        remove(filename);
        return -4; /* Error reading source. */
    }
    if (fclose(source)) {
        fclose(target);
        remove(filename);
        return -4; /* Error closing source (delayed read error). */
    }

    if (ferror(target) || fflush(target)) {
        fclose(target);
        remove(filename);
        return -5; /* Write error */
    }
    if (fclose(target)) {
        remove(filename);
        return -5; /* Error closing target; delayed write error */
    }

    /* Success. */
    return 0;
}
```

which is particularly careful against read and write errors.  It is not blazingly fast, because it relies on the C library to buffer the input, but it is not horribly slow, either.  The fact that it does not use any explicit buffers (relying on the standard C library to decide how to buffer the source and the file being written) makes it quite acceptable overall, actually.

Conversion to a new buffer, or in place, is rather similar:

```
size_t  decode_quoted_printable(char *dst, const char *src)
{
    const char *const origin = dst;

    /* Neither pointer may be NULL. src == dst is okay, however. */
    if (!dst || !src) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return 0;
    }

    /* Copy loop. */
    while (*src)
        if (*src == '=') {
            if (src[1] == '\0') {
                /* '=' at the end of string. Skipped. */
                break;
            } else
            if (src[1] == '\n') {
                /* Soft newline. Skip both =\n and =\n\r newlines. */
                if (src[2] == '\r')
                    src += 3;
                else
                    src += 2;
            } else
            if (src[1] == '\r') {
                /* Soft newline. Skip both =\r and =\r\n newlines. */
                if (src[2] == '\n')
                    src += 3;
                else
                    src += 2;
            } else {
                const int  hi = hex_digit((unsigned char)(src[1]));
                const int  lo = hex_digit((unsigned char)(src[2]));
                if (hi >= 0 && lo >= 0) {
                    *(dst++) = lo + 16*hi;
                    src += 3;
                } else {
                    /* Error in input format. We are permissive,
                       and reproduce the erroneous `=XY` as-is. */
                    *(dst++) = *(src++);
                }
            }
        } else
        if (*src == '\n') {
            if (src[1] == '\r')
                src += 2;
            else
                src += 1;
            *(dst++) = '\n';
        } else
        if (*src == '\r') {
            if (src[1] == '\n')
                src += 2;
            else
                src += 1;
            *(dst++) = '\n';
        } else
           *(dst++) = *(src++);

    /* Terminate result to make it a string. */
    *dst = '\0';

    /* Just in case the source was an empty string, we clear
       errno to zero.  This also means we always set errno,
       which is a bit rare, but makes the use of this function
       easy: errno is nonzero iff there was an error. */
    errno = 0;
    return (size_t)(dst - origin);
}
```

Note that because string literals cannot be modified, you cannot do `char *data = "foo"; decode_quoted_printable(foo, foo);`.

You can do `char data[] = "foo"; decode_quoted_printable(foo, foo);`, however, because that declares an array of chars that just happens to be initialized to the string `"foo"`.

Note that the above function also does automatic universal newline conversion.  That is, it supports all four newline conventions, `\r\n`, `\n\r`, `\r`, and `\n`, and converts them all to the standard C `\n` newlines.

The destination buffer must be at least as long as the source buffer, and you can use the same destination buffer as the source, as long as it is mutable (not a literal string, nor pointing to a literal string).

The difference to the get-one-decoded-character from a stream approach is that this latter one requires the entire content to be in an in-memory buffer.  Whether that is a plus or a minus, depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that should get you started.

I've tested it and it seems to work for the input you gave. It has *some* error checking, but not a lot.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// hexnib -- convert ascii hex digit to binary value
int
hexnib(int chr)
{

    chr &= 0xFF;

    do {
        if ((chr >= '0') && (chr <= '9')) {
            chr -= '0';
            break;
        }

        if ((chr >= 'A') && (chr <= 'F')) {
            chr -= 'A';
            chr += 10;
            break;
        }

        // error ...
    } while (0);

    return chr;
}

void
convert(char *utf8,const char *quo)
{
    int chr;
    int acc;

    while (1) {
        chr = *quo++;
        if (chr == 0)
            break;

        // handle ordinary char (i.e. _not_ start of =XY)
        if (chr != '=') {
            *utf8++ = chr;
            continue;
        }

        // hex value accumulator
        acc = 0;

        // get X value
        chr = *quo++;
        if (chr == 0)
            break;

        // convert to binary
        chr = hexnib(chr);
        acc <<= 8;
        acc |= chr;

        // get Y value
        chr = *quo++;
        if (chr == 0)
            break;

        // convert to binary
        chr = hexnib(chr);
        acc <<= 8;
        acc |= chr;

        // store utf sequence
        *utf8++ = acc;
    }

    // store end of string
    *utf8 = 0;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *fname;
    FILE *fi;
    char ibuf[1000];
    char obuf[1000];

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    fname = *argv;
    if (fname != NULL)
        fi = fopen(fname,"r");
    else
        fi = stdin;

    while (1) {
        char *cp = fgets(ibuf,sizeof(ibuf),fi);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        convert(obuf,ibuf);

        fputs(obuf,stdout);
    }

    if (fname != NULL)
        fclose(fi);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux Thanks. It also had other issues as well. I've coded [and tested] the full program